# Error creating a database from existing SQL Server Database bacpac file in AWS RDS MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

How can I create a MS SQL Server database from an existing database in AWS.
I have a `.bacpac` file which when imported gets me the schema as well as the data but AWS does not seem to allow me do that when i try to do that using the SQL server management studio. it give an error stating no permissions.
Can any one guide me there.